# Laravel Lighthouse GraphQL validation based on related model

Tags: laravel, validation, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Using Laravel Lighthouse GraphQL, i would like to validate a value in one model so that it always matches the value in a related model.

In this case a `Program` has a `year_id` and a `Category` also has a `year_id`. I want to validate that the `Program` and the `Category` use the same `year_id`.

The GraphQL Schema looks like this:

```graphql
input CreateCategory {
    year_id: ID!
    name: String!
}

input CreateProgram {
    year_id: ID!
    name: String!
    category: CreateCategoryRelation
}

input CreateCategoryRelation {
    connect: ID
}
```

Now if I create a `Category` with `year_id: 1` (return Category id=1):

```graphql
mutation {
  createCategory(input:{
    year_id: 1
    name: "category in year 1"
  }) {
    name
    id
  }
}
```

And then try to create a `Program` with `year_id: 2` related to the new `Category`

```graphql
mutation {
  createProgram(input:{
    year_id: 2
    name: "Program in year 2"
    category: {
      connect: 1
    }
  }) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

I would like the validation so fail with a message like **"You cannot create a Program in a different year as it's Category!"**

So far I could not find a way to validate based on any value in another model.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your own validation with https://lighthouse-php.com/4.7/security/validation.html#validate-fields

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the answer from Enzo Notario, I found a solution.
In case others would like more details on how you **could** (I'm sure this can be done prettier) write your own validation, here is my code:

```graphql
type Mutation {
    createProgram(input: CreateProgram! @spread): Program! @create @yearValidation
}
```

file App/GraphQL/Directives/YearValidationDirective.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Directives;

use App\Rules\SameYear;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Schema\Directives\ValidationDirective;

class YearValidationDirective extends ValidationDirective
{
    /**
     * List of all relations that should be checked for having the same year
     */
    private $relations = [
        'category' => true
    ];

    /**
     * Name of the directive.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function name(): string
    {
        return 'yearValidation';
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed[]
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        if (isset($this->args['year_id'])) {
            // year_id is given, get it
            $year_id = $this->args['year_id'];
        } else {
            // year_id not given, get it from the model
            $id = $this->args['id'];
            $fieldName = $this->resolveInfo->fieldName; // "updateTableName"
            $tableName = substr($fieldName, 6);
            $year_id= DB::table($tableName)->findOrFail($id)->year_id;
        }

        $relationFields = [];

        foreach($this->args as $field => $arg) {
            if (is_array($arg) && isset($this->relations[$field])) {
                $relationFields[$field] = [new SameYear($year_id)];
            }
        }

        return $relationFields;
    }
}
```

File App/Rules/SameYear.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class SameYear implements Rule
{
    protected $year_id;
    protected $found_year_id;
    protected $tableName;
    protected $connect;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($year_id)
    {
        $this->year_id = $year_id;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $this->connect = $value['connect'];
        $this->tableName = ucfirst($attribute);
        $this->found_year_id = DB::table($this->tableName)->find($this->connect)->year_id;
        return intval($this->found_year_id) === intval($this->year_id);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return "Year_id's must be the same! $this->tableName (id: $this->connect) must have year_id: $this->year_id (found: $this->found_year_id)";
    }
}
```

This does the job for me.